# Java String Matches

Tags: java, string

Buenas estoy generando un pequeño código de comprobación utilizando la sentencia matches, requiero de poder comprobar que los datos de un segundo String estén en uno digitado anterior

```js
//Asignacion de las variables del programa
        String a, b, op;
        //Ciclo para efectuar el proceso 
        do {
            //Valida si se desea iniciar el proceso
            op = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Desea realizar una Sentencia Match: (Si o No)");
            // valida la seleccion del usuario
            if (op.equalsIgnoreCase("si") == true) {
                //Solicita al usuario la frase u oracion a analizar
                a = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Por favor digite la oracion: ");
                //solicita al usuario que valor desea comprobar que este en la sentencia
                b = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite la sentencia con la que desea comprobar: ");
                //comprobacion de los datos ingresados
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, a);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, b);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, a.matches(b));
                boolean test =a.matches(b);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, a.matches(b));
                if (test== true) {
                    //Envia mensaje en pantalla para indicar si la sentencia esta dentro de la oracion inicial

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Dentro de la primera sentencia: " + a + " \n "
                            + "SI concuerda con : " + b);
                } else {
                    //informa sobre el resultado obtenido
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La sentencia " + b + " No esta dentro de lo digitado");
                }

            }

        } while (op.equalsIgnoreCase("si"));
```

Pero este me da un problema si la sentencia a es muy larga, ocupo realizarlo con este método.

Comment: Que problema, cual es un ejemplo de sentencia?

Comment: Es decir en a deseo ingresar: hoy es martes y en b validar si tiene o incluye la palabra martes, utilizando el metodo matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal y como lo tienes, el segundo string no tiene que estar dentro del primero, tiene que ser igual, supongo tienes que crear la expresión regular adecuada para comprobar que está dentro,

```
 boolean test = a.matches( "(.*)" + b + "(.*)" );
```

Comment: Voy a realizar el cambio y la prueba gracias